# Regular expression matching space but at the end of line

Tags: regex

I'm trying to replace multiple spaces with a single one, but at the start of the line.

Example:

```
___abc___def__
___ghi___jkl__
```

should turn to

```
___abc_def__
___ghi_jkl__
```

*Note that I've replaced space with underscore*

A simple search using the following pattern:

```
([^\s])\s+
```

matches the space at the end of the first line up to the space at the beginning of the next one.

So, if I replace with `\1_`, I get the following:

```
___abc_def_ghi_jkl
```

And that is absolutely not what I expect and regex engines, e.g., PowerGREP or the one in Visual Studio, don't behave that way.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. Please edit your question and add sample strings and expected results.

Comment: Please specify exactly [which regular expression dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) you're using, whenever asking about regex.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to match only horizontal spaces, use `\h`:

Find what: `(?<=\S)\h+(?=\S)` 
Replace with:   (a space)

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible interpretations of the question. For each of them the replacement will be a single space character.

- If spaces is plural and means space characters but not tabs then use
  a find string of `(^ {2,})|( {2,}$)`.
- If spaces is plural and should includes tabs then use a find string
  of `(^[ \t]{2,})|([ \t]{2,}$)`.
- If any leading or trailing spaces and tabs (one or more) is to be
  replaced with a space then use a find string of `(^[ \t]+)|([ \t]+$)`.

The general form of each of these is `(^...)|(...$)`. The `|` means an alternation so either the preceding or the following bracketed expression can match. Hence the find what text can match either at the beginning or the end of a line. The `...` varies depending on exactly what needs to be matched. Specifying `[ \t]` means only the two characters space and tab, whereas `\s` includes the line-end characters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the intention was to replace this:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;Hey diddle&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;diddle,&nbsp;&nbsp;\n<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;The&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cat and the fiddle,\n
```

with this:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;Hey diddle diddle,\n<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;The Cat and the fiddle,\n
```

A slightly modified version of [Toto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645513/regular-expression-matching-space-but-at-the-end-of-line/28645558#28645558) did the trick:

```
(?<=\S)\h+(?=\S)|\s+$
```

finding any space(s) between word-characters *and* trailing space at the end of the line.

Comment: Please edit the question to specify what exactly was being asked; then, choose an answer as correct.